# wine installation error nothing working

Tags: lubuntu

I tried Using Terminal But,

```
$ apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.`

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

In synaptic Package Manager I get the error:

```
Could not apply changes!
Fix broken packages first.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

First remove wine already installed : `sudo apt-get remove wine`

Then tries to fix broken packages   : `sudo apt-get -f install`

Finally the update command to update the packages in system : `sudo apt-get update`

Now you try to install wine package : `sudo apt-get install wine`

Again you get error messages, show us the session